# MathJax: How do I remove the "Typesetting math: 100%" display message

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I'm using MathJax to render some math. How do I get rid of this message in the bottom left? I can't find this in MathJax's [docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/index.html).

[image: screenshot of mathjax display]

Comment: that might be the statusbar https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Hide-render-statusbar

Comment: Yeah! Adding `messageStyle: none` fixes this. Thanks! I see now that this is in fact documented here: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html

Comment: It's just quite hidden as I wouldn't have guessed it was a status bar either. Just searched for "mathjax typsetting math" and it sounded about right. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a status bar. Per [MathJax-Docs](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Hide-render-statusbar), you can turn it off by setting the message style to none before you load mathjax:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  messageStyle: "none"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your suggested script still shows a message at the bottom of the page as I have shown in my response below. Is there any way of getting rid of that message, as well?

Comment: @nam since there have been lib updates since 2 years ago you need to hit up docs.mathjax.org and find the current way to set the config. "messageStyle" is listed as having been updated in 2.7 specifically. If you can't figure it out by looking through the docs please create a new question and reference this question as not working for your current version. Asking on this question won't really help you.